# Add TextBox.Text to a list using a for loop

Tags: c#

I am trying to take the values in the textboxes, named sequentially from 0-9, and add that to a List using a for loop. I am having problems with the syntax or something.

here is what I have now.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= amt.Count(); i++)
        {
            amt[i] = int.Parse(amtBox[i].Text);
        }
```

The error is that amtBox doesnt exist in the current context.

My problem is within the loop where i have amtBox[i].Text. I have tried this several ways and VS always throws an error. I have tried "amtBox" + i and that compiles but then causes an error when I try to do something with it and says "data is of wrong type".

I am new to C# and come from PHP so maybe that is why I think this approach will work. PHP doesnt care about data types where C# really does. I have done this exact thing in PHP many times without any issue.

Any suggestions on another way to do this are appreciated as I am probably coming at this all wrong.

Thanks

Comment: no its an int public static List<int> amt = new List <int>(); This is because I need to use the Sum() function later.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment.  What are the contents of the textboxes?  If any of them are empty, or contain non-integer values (text, or numbers with decimal places, etc) then you will get an error.  And what is the exact error message?  That's greatly helpful in troubleshooting.

Comment: i have taken care of that elsewhere in the code so there is always at least a 0 in the textbox to keep from breaking Sum(). I am going to make sure they only contain integers in the future but for right now I am only inserting values of type int.

Comment: How are the textboxes named? Are they only named "0"..."9" or are they "amtBox0"..."amtBox9"?

Comment: amtBox0-9. i have a button to add more if needed but that shouldnt matter here. it is teh reason i need to loop to add them though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to declare an array and assign amtBox'es to the individual indexes in the array and then you can iterate on that array.

```
var amtBoxes = new TextBox[] { amtBox0, amtBox1, .... };
for (int i = 0; i <= amt.Count(); i++)
{
    amt[i] = int.Parse(amtBoxes[i].Text);
}
```

If you end up needing to iterate on your TextBox controls in other places I would consider making the array an instance member of your object.

Comment: I think this would work if i wasnt using amt.Count(). there is nothing in the array so it gives me an index error, which makes sense.

Comment: @JohnS  I wrote the code under the assumption that the amt list was already initialized and had all values it needs.  Otherwise, you could call amt.Add(int.Parse(amtBoxes[i].Text));  But you'll need to clear the list prior to interating on the TextBox array.  If your amt list is of a fixed size, I would suggest making that an array instead of a list.

Comment: its not a fixed size, thats why I chose list. I actually have another method that adds a new set of textboxes to the form. I do initialize the list and I clear it before iterating. the loop is kind of a necessity, at least the way I see it, so I can add new items dynamically. Now that I think about it my statement was wrong as it says <= I was thinking =.

Comment: This answer seemed to get me the closest but I decided to just go with arrays and remove the add method. thanks and I did learn a few things.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your textbox are named "amtBox" + a number. 
(The Name property is "amtBox1" as an example)

In this case you could use

```
 Control[] t = Controls.Find("amtBox" + i, false);
```

for a code like this

```
for (int i = 0; i <= amt.Count(); i++)  
{  
    Control[] t = Controls.Find("amtBox" + i, false);
    if(t != null && t.Length > 0)
    {
        amt[i] = int.Parse(t[0].Text);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Your assumption is right. I saw something along the lines of this in another post and wasnt sure how to add this to my loop. could you provide the full code to add it to my list?

Comment: Controls.Find("amtBox" + i) throws an error that "no overload for method 'Find' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: Yep, I have corrected the answer. The Find method requires another param. A boolean to check control containers (a panel that contains textboxes for example) also, because the name of a control doesn't need to be unique, the Find method returns an array of possible controls with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you have text boxes named `amtBox1`, `amtBox2`, etc., and what you are trying to do is sequence through them.  As you point out, this is very easy in PHP.  It is possible to do what you're suggesting using reflection, but that is expensive and, in any event, there's probably a better way to do what you're looking for.

You could put all of your amount boxes into an array, and then what you have would work:

```
var amtBoxes = new[] {
    amtBox1,
    amtBox2,
    amtBox3
}
```