# Control array type loop in C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, control-array

I am writing a C#/ASP.Net web application and I have a large number of text boxes that need to be set to variable values in the code behind. Currently I am doing the following:

```
AspTextBox0.Text = codeBehindVariable[0];
AspTextBox1.Text = codeBehindVariable[1];
AspTextBox2.Text = codeBehindVariable[2];
AspTextBox3.Text = codeBehindVariable[3];
…
```

Is there an easy way to do this in a simple “for” loop??

This is a very simplified example, the real program has a switch case and some other testing that needs to be performed at the time the variable is assigned. Therefore, a “for” loop would drastically simplify the writing and maintainability of the code. Back in the good-old-days of VB6 and control arrays this was a piece of cake.

Comment: A similar posting:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150008/add-textbox-text-to-a-list-using-a-for-loop/12150177#12150177 -- you have array on the right, the link has it with the array on the left

Answer (score 6):

The *good old days of VB6* are long gone and better don't come back.

Create a control array or better a `List<TextBox>` yourself:

```
var textBoxes = new List<TextBox> {
    AspTextBox0,
    AspTextBox1,
    // ...
};
```

Then **[Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx)** it with the `codeBehindVariable`:

```
textBoxes.Zip(codeBehindVariable, 
              (textBox, variable) => textBox.Text = variable);
```

Or, if you prefer a `for` loop:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < codeBehindVariable.Length; i++ )
{
    textBoxes[i].Text = codeBehindVariable[i];
}
```

Keep in mind that in the `for` loop you will have to make sure that both `textBoxes` and `codeBehindVariable` have the same number of items (or make the loop run only over the shortest list's amount of entries). The `Zip` function will take care of this by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in a class that implements `System.Web.UI.Page` you can try to look up the control to find the one you want like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= codeBehindVariable.Length; i++)  
{ 
  var textBox = FindControl("AspTextBox" + i, false);
  if(textBox != null)
  {
    textBox.Text = codeBehindVariable[i];  
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this...

```
    int i = 0;
    foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox tempTextBox = (TextBox)ctrl;
            tempTextBox.Text = codeBehindVariable[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You will still need to check the name of the control if it is a TextBox to see if it is AspTextBox0, AspTextBox1, etc... you should not rely on the control order in Controls